# Allowing Traffic Across the Interface Members of a pfSense Bridge

Tags: pfsense

I have the following setup on pfSense 2.0.1 32 bit:

```
WAN_IF (Physical Interface Connected to ISP)-----\     /-----DMZ (Physical Interface of External Servers)
                                                  \   /
                                                   \ /
                 WAN_BR (Bridge of the Two Physical Interfaces, Used as WAN Connection)
                                                    |
                                             pfSense Firewall
                                                    |
                                 LAN (Physical Interface Connected to LAN)
```

I want to allows traffic to cross between the servers and ISP without interuption, but I don't want either having access to my LAN.

**What firewall rules do I apply to allow for this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you need to permit outbound from those servers. Assuming you're using the default of filtering on member interfaces and not the bridge itself, just make sure you're not permitting traffic to your LAN subnet on the DMZ firewall rules. If you need to permit some outbound traffic on DMZ to any destination, add a block rule above all your pass rules with the destination of your LAN subnet to ensure those rules can't apply to LAN-destined traffic.